# ssh: connect to host git.censored.de port 22: Connection refused

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I have my own V-Server on which only gitlab should run. So I followed the installation of Gitlab for Ubuntu 22.04 and everything worked fine. Then I added an SSH key and wanted to push a repo and then the following error:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

```
ssh: connect to host git.censored.de port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
The port of my V-Server is 23, I changed it because I thought that git uses port 22 and so my server cannot use it at the same time, but then I get the message above. If I change the port of my V-Server back to 22 and then enter the command again. Then the terminal asks me for a password for the git user. What can I do about this?

Here is my config

```
external_url 'https://git.censored.de'
letsencrypt['enable'] = false
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/git.censored.de/fullchain.pem"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/git.censored.de/privkey.pem"
gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 22
```